# Why don't my environment variables in .bashrc get recognized?

Tags: linux

I am trying to set environment variables in the .baschrc or .bash_profile files. They both look like this (The first row was there before):

```
export GUROBI_HOME="/NOC/gurobi/gurobi651/linux64"
export PATH="${PATH}:${GUROBI_HOME}/bin"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${GUROBI_HOME}/lib"
```

However, in the command prompt, when I type the following:

```
echo $GUROBI_HOME
```

I get the error that the variable is undefined.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You mean `.bashrc`? type `cd ~ ; source .bashrc ; echo ${GUROBI_HOME}`, do you still get the same error?

Comment: what users `.bashrc` are the variables defined? if in roots and your are regular user or vice versa these will not be defined for the current user you are logged in as.

Comment: What Linux distribution, or more accurately, what shell are you using?

Comment: I ended up abandoning this library for another environment. Thank you all.